# UIButton in Custom UITableView Cell, background colors not changing after reloadRows or InsertRows called on the tableview with new data from sockets

Tags: uitableview, uibutton, swift4

I have a custom uitableviewcell with uilabels and uibuttons. I'm getting new data from web sockets and updating the uibuttons by reloading a section or inserting a new section in the data is not in the table view. The uibuttons are initially white and are supposed to turn to a yellow background color when pressed and back to white background color when pressed again.

When i first load the data everything works well. **The problem comes when i reload a section with new data from the web sockets.The uibuttons background color stays white and does not change to yellow. I'm not sure what the problem is but i suspect that after reloading a tableviewcell section something happens that changes the behaviour of the uibuttons. Any help on how i can go around this. I will really appreciate. I'm using swift4**.

Comment: Do you store the state of the button (selected/not selected - e.g. white color or yellow) somewhere between your `tableView.reload` calls?

Comment: Hacked this problem. Thanks to all who took a look at it!